# How to use ko.utils.range inside template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've created a pager template for a knockout viewmodel

```
<script type="text/html" id="custom_pager_template">

    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
        <!-- ko foreach: ko.utils.range(0, maxPageIndex) -->\
        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data + 1, click function() { $root.currentpageindex($data) }, css { selected $data= =$root.currentPageIndex() }"><span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>

</script>
```

But when i run this i get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to process binding "simpleGrid: function
>   (){return gridViewModel }" Message: Unable to process binding
>   "foreach: function (){return ko.utils.range(0,maxPageIndex) }"
>   Message: Unable to parse bindings. Bindings value: text: $data + 1,
>   click function() { $root.currentpageindex($data) }, css { selected
>   $data= =$root.currentPageIndex() } Message: Unexpected token )

So how can i use ko functions inside a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing <strike>two</strike>three colon's

the first 2 are here

```
css { selected $data= =$root.currentPageIndex() }
```

should be

```
css: { selected: $data == $root.currentPageIndex() }
```

and the final one is here:

```
click function() { ... }
```

should be

```
click: function() { ... }
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rkz66/

Comment: Missing one on click too

Comment: Indeed, thank you.
I thought it had to do with the ko.utils.range, should have read the error message more thoroughly.